# how can I access react localhost from my phone?

Tags: reactjs, mobile, browser, localhost

i want to see my react app on my phone. But when I paste the network link it doesn't load anything or localhost refuse.

i tried changing the localhost to 3006 instead of 3000 but nothing changed, i tried turning off my firewall and it's still not loading anything.

Comment: use the host's local ip address instead of localhost. If you have windows, you can see it by running ipconfig in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your app is running on `localhost:30000` (it can be any port)
2. on your phone instead of localhost use your `Local IP Address` (not your public IP address). You can find your local IP under Network settings.
3. Make sure to add the port at the end of the IP address like what you
   do with localhost. Like: HTTP://123.123.1.23:3000

You can refer to [this article](https://prowe214.medium.com/tip-how-to-view-localhost-web-apps-on-your-phone-ad6b2c883a7c) for more detail